# Histogram in matplotlib, time on x-Axis

Tags: python, time, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I am new to matplotlib (1.3.1-2) and I cannot find a decent place to start.
I want to plot the distribution of points over time in a histogram with matplotlib.

Basically I want to plot the cumulative sum of the occurrence of a date.

```
date
2011-12-13
2011-12-13
2013-11-01
2013-11-01
2013-06-04
2013-06-04
2014-01-01
...
```

That would make

```
2011-12-13 -> 2 times
2013-11-01 -> 3 times
2013-06-04 -> 2 times
2014-01-01 -> once
```

Since there will be many points over many years, I want to set the `start date` on my `x-Axis` and the `end date`, and then mark `n-time steps`(i.e. 1 year steps) and finally decide how many `bins` there will be.

How would I achieve that?

Comment: What format has your data? `datetime` objects?

Comment: @hitzg Unix timecode. but I can reformat into `datetime`

Comment: @Stophface BTW If you have `datetime` already you can just do `plt.hist(data_as_datetime)`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Matplotlib uses its own format for dates/times, but also provides simple functions to convert which are provided in the `dates` module. It also provides various `Locators` and `Formatters` that take care of placing the ticks on the axis and formatting the corresponding labels. This should get you started:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# generate some random data (approximately over 5 years)
data = [float(random.randint(1271517521, 1429197513)) for _ in range(1000)]

# convert the epoch format to matplotlib date format 
mpl_data = mdates.epoch2num(data)

# plot it
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.hist(mpl_data, bins=50, color='lightblue')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d.%m.%y'))
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

To add to hitzg's answer, you can use `AutoDateLocator` and `AutoDateFormatter` to have matplotlib do the location and formatting for you:

```
locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(locator))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more modern solution for matplotlib version 3.5.3.

Also, it explicitly specifies the min/max date instead of relying on min/max values derived from the data.

```
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

days = 365*3
start_date = datetime.now()
random_dates = [
    start_date + timedelta(days=int(random.random()*days))
    for _ in range(100)
]
end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=days)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,3))
n, bins, patches = ax.hist(random_dates, bins=52, range=(start_date, end_date))
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram with time on x-axis]